# Swift Generic doesn't infer as expected

Tags: swift, generics

The code below causes compile error.

How can I do something like this with swift generic? Or is it impossible?

```
func
S( _ p: UnsafePointer< Float  >  ) {
}
func
S( _ p: UnsafePointer< Double > ) {
}
func
Sum< N >( _ p: UnsafePointer< N > ) {
    S( p )
}
```

Compile error:

> ```
> Cannot invoke 'S' with an argument list of type '(UnsafePointer<N>)'
> ```

Comment: Well, you cannot use Double or Float when all you got is Numeric.

Comment: OK, I simplified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Be sure to see Rob Mayoff's answer as well. While this answer is closer to the original question and explains some important concepts, if I were building this myself, I'd probably use something closer to his. His also is memory safe, which this answer is not, because I was copying from the original question.)

You want to do this in the other direction. Based on your original code (which uses `baseAddress` unsafely, but leaving that for now):

```
import Accelerate

func sum( _ p: ArraySlice<Float>) -> Float {
    return sum(p, summer: vDSP_sve)
}

func sum( _ p: ArraySlice<Double>) -> Double {
    return sum(p, summer: vDSP_sveD)
}

typealias Summer<N: Numeric> = (UnsafePointer<N>, vDSP_Stride, UnsafeMutablePointer<N>, vDSP_Length) -> Void

func sum<N: Numeric>(_ p: ArraySlice<N>, summer: Summer<N>) -> N {
    var v: N = 0
    summer(  p.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress! }
        ,   vDSP_Stride( 1 )
        ,   &v
        ,   vDSP_Length( p.count )
    )
    return v
}
```

The least generic functions (the ones that apply only to Float or Double) should call the most generic function (the one that works on Numeric), passing the part that changes (the Accelerate function).

Consider the case in your code where I call `Sum` on a list of `Int` (which is also `Numeric`). What "S" would it call in that case? This is why you go from least generic to most rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to define a sub-protocol of `Numeric` that wraps the vDSP API:

```
import Accelerate

protocol Acceleratable: Numeric {
    static func acceleratedSum(ofElementsStartingAt basePointer: UnsafePointer<Self>, stride: vDSP_Stride, count: vDSP_Length) -> Self
}

extension Float: Acceleratable {
    static func acceleratedSum(ofElementsStartingAt basePointer: UnsafePointer<Float>, stride: vDSP_Stride, count: vDSP_Length) -> Float {
        var sum: Float = 0
        vDSP_sve(basePointer, stride, &sum, count)
        return sum
    }
}

extension Double: Acceleratable {
    static func acceleratedSum(ofElementsStartingAt basePointer: UnsafePointer<Double>, stride: vDSP_Stride, count: vDSP_Length) -> Double {
        var sum: Double = 0
        vDSP_sveD(basePointer, stride, &sum, count)
        return sum
    }
}

extension ArraySlice where Element: Acceleratable {
    func acceleratedSum() -> Element {
        return withUnsafeBufferPointer {
            guard let base = $0.baseAddress else { return 0 }
            return Element.acceleratedSum(ofElementsStartingAt: base, stride: 1, count: numericCast($0.count))
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Acceleratable {
    func acceleratedSum() -> Element {
        return self[...].acceleratedSum()
    }
}

let doubles: [Double] = [2, 3, 5]
print(doubles.acceleratedSum())

let floats: [Float] = [3, 1, 4]
print(floats.acceleratedSum())
```